# C#, EF Core CosmosDB - could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

Using this very simple (IMHO) line of code I and getting below error.  I am using EF and CosmosDB.  I have tried calling 'ToList' and others per the error, but no luck.  Perhaps something simple that I just cannot see?  Thanks for any help!

public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection> Handle(GetMyUpcomingGamesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
var cutoffTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-120);

```
// THIS IS HORRIBLE AND YOU NEED TO FIX IT !!!!

//  var results = await _repository.GetAsync(o => o.Begins > cutoffTime);

var playerResults = await _repository.GetAsync(o => o.Players.Any(p => 
    p.Id.Equals(request.ProfileId)));//

var response = _mapper.Map<IReadOnlyCollection<GameResponse>>(playerResults);

return response;
```

}

```
>    System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GameReadModel>()
        .Where(g => EF.Property<IReadOnlyCollection<ProfileReadModel>>(g, "Players")
            .AsQueryable()
            .Any(o => o.Id.Equals(__request_ProfileId_0)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https:



Implementation of GetAsync(): 

GetAsync implementation: public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<GameReadModel>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<GameReadModel, bool>> predicate) { var results = _context.GameReadModels.Where(predicate); return await results.ToListAsync(); }


Model:

namespace Common.Domain.ReadModels
{
    public class GameReadModel 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public VenueReadModel Venue { get; set; } 

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Begins { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Ends { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfPlayers { get; set; }

        public decimal MinimumRating { get; set; }

        public decimal MaximumRating { get; set; }

        public bool OpenToLobby { get; set; }

        public string GameType { get; set; }

        public ProfileReadModel Host { get; set; } 

        public IReadOnlyCollection<ProfileReadModel> Players { get; set; }
        
        public IReadOnlyCollection<ListItemReadModel> Lists { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }
    }
}


using Common.Domain.Abstracts;

namespace Common.Domain.ReadModels
{
    public class ProfileReadModel 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string SocialId { get; set; }

        public string Handle { get; set; }

        public decimal Rating { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the implementatoin of `GetAsync` in the repository, as well as the relevant entity classes. It looks like it's calling `AsQueryable` somewhere, and that's usually a red flag.

Comment: It is your [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32626)? If yes, you have to use `FromSql`.

Comment: ".Any" returns a bool; your code seems to imply you're expecting a "result set".

Comment: There no EF code in the question and CosmosDB isn't an RDBMS so this is anything but simple. ORMs like EF try to give the impression of working with in-memory object graphs, like object databases so they don't need any kind of CRUD classes. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. The illusion breaks at points though and doc DBs are far closer to object databases than relational ones. A document already is a graph of "objects". The navigation direction plays a huge role. Some relations are to nested objects so very cheap and easy to translate. Others follow refs

Comment: @GerrySchmitz: Pay closer attention. `.Any` is being used on a child entity collection. The code is getting (or at least attempting to get) a result set of parent entities (`GameReadModel`) that have at least one matching child entity (`ProfileReadModel`).

Comment: Try looking for a player's games instead filtering by each game's player. In RDBMSs JOINs have no direction and perform the same as long as there indexes. In a doc DB though following a reference from one direction to another can be very expensive if there are a lot of "lefts" and just a few or one "right". This is unusual enough that the LINQ translation was missed

Comment: You seem to be trolling me (@madreflection). (See his previous comment to me) You're obfustication doesn't negate the fact that ".Any returns a bool".

Comment: I'm not trolling you. I'm pointing out that you're comments have missed the point. The fact that `.Any` returns a bool isn't related to expecting a result set because different entities are involved.

Comment: GetAsync implementation: 

        public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<GameReadModel>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<GameReadModel, bool>> predicate)
        {
            var results = _context.GameReadModels.Where(predicate);
            return await results.ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: [Edit] the question and add it there, not in the comments. And it looks like we need the models that are involved, too.

Comment: @shamusschubert did you try starting from the *player* instead of the games? Did you try filtering by a Player instead of a player's ID? You aren't working with a relational database. Depending on how you designed your documents (the classes aren't the actual documents) the `Game`  doc may *contain* `Players` in which case the lookup is fast and easy, or it may only have an HREF to a separate entity, in which case lookup is very slow - slow enough that it's almost always avoided in document databases. If you start with a player though, you're looking for exact matches for that HREF

Comment: Players do not have 'games' in their materialized views.  This app uses CQRS and has read and write stores that are optimized for queries versus writes.  The Game has a collection of players only.  I could materialized the 'player' and try contains.  Let me give that a try.  Seems like I have never run into this issues before and use the Any() pretty frequently to filter parent lists by child complex elements.  Almost feels like I made a dumb mistake and cannot put my finger on it.  Thanks I will try again.

Comment: Materializing the Player and using Contains() resulted in the same error.   Thx though.